# Processing excel files with data reader: ExecuteReader() buffers entire file

Tags: c#, excel, datareader

I'm running into a peculiar issue when trying to process large excel files (300mb+) using a data reader.
The following code illustrates the way I open the excel file and iterate over the rows in sheet 'largesheet$':

```
const string inputFilePath = @"C:\largefile.xlsx";
const string connectionString =
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;\";Data Source=" +
    inputFilePath;

// Initialize connection
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    // Open connection
    connection.Open();

    // Configure command
    var command = new OleDbCommand("largesheet$", connection) {CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect};

    // Execute reader
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // <-- Completely loads file/sheet into memory

    // Iterate results
    while (reader.HasRows)
    {
        // Read single row
        reader.Read();

        // ...
    }

    // Close connection
    connection.Close();
}
```

In my understanding this should open the excel file and load each row when needed by using the *reader.Read()* statement.
However, it appears that the *ExecuteReader()* statement does more than returning an OleDbDataReader instance. Using breakpoints I noticed that that one statement takes 30s+, and the Windows Resource Monitor indicates a steady increase of allocated memory during the execution of that statement.
Specifying the *CommandBehavior* parameter (e.g. *SequentialAccess*) of the ExecuteReader() method has no effect.

What am I doing wrong here? Are there alternative ways of processing large (excel) files?

**Note**: the IMEX & HDR extended properties of the connection string are intentional.

**Edit**: After some rational thinking I assume it is not possible to process an excel file without buffering it one way or another. Since excel files are basically a glorified collection of compressed XML files it is not possible to process a worksheet without decompressing it (and keeping it in ram or temporarily saving to disk).
The only alternative I can think of is using [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel). Not sure how [OpenXML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/) handles it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "All rows and columns of the named table or tables will be returned when you call one of the Execute methods of a Command object." (under the Remarks section).  So this would appear to be the default behavior of ExecuteReader().

[ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aet5yz0b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may give you more options, particularly when CommandBehavior is set to [SequentialAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), though you would need to handle reading at the byte level.

Comment: As I stated in my question, the use of _SequentialAccess_ makes no difference (I have only tried this in combination with _TableDirect_). I find it peculiar that ExecuteReader loads the data into memory, I thought one of the advantages of data readers was their agility and performance. Does the .NET framework offer any alternatives that are more suitable for processing large data files?

Comment: Have you considered using OpenXML (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for your tasks?  This may give you more control, depending on what you need to do with the data once it is loaded.  You could use the SAX-like reading provided by the SDK to control how the file is read.